# PHP Password Reset URL processing

Tags: php, url, passwords

How do I (and should I?) store the reset code from password reset URL to process the password reset?

In short, I'm trying to create a password reset system where the user enters their email address which generates a random reset code which is appended to a URL which is then emailed to the user.

The user then clicks on the link and is taken to the password reset page. The reset code and email are taken from the URL and stored in variables. Those variables are then used when the new passwords are submitted to check if they match the database and of they are, will update the passwords.

The problem I think I am having is that reset.php is the page being used to 'action' the new password form so when the new passwords are submitted there are no values in the URL only when the page first loads from the link and even then the rest code and email values do not seem to store in the variables created.

How can I keep the values and which URL should I use to 'action' the form to ensure this works? Am I approaching this in completely the wrong way?

Hope this makes sense and someone can help? Please explain in simple terms as I'm quite new to PHP and particularly with regards to passwords etc.

Shortened code (should be clear enough to see the issue):

```
<?php

require("../db_connect.php");
$page_title = "Password Reset";
$errors = array();

// check if reset code and email is set in URL and store in variable if it is
// example URL http://www.thissite.com/reset.php?reset=123abc&email=me@me.com

if (!isset($_GET['reset']) || (!isset($_GET['email']))
{ 
  //create error message and link to forgotten password page 
}

else

{ 
  $reset_from_url = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc , $_GET['reset'] );
  $email_from_url = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc , $_GET['email'] );
}

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
{ 
  // code to compare reset code and email from URL with database
  // code to check passwords entered and if all ok, insert into database
}

<form action="reset.php" method="POST">
<p>New password:</p>
<input type = "password">
</p>Confirm Password:</p>
<input type = "password">
</form>
```

Comment: You will more than likely need to store the reset code and email as a hidden field on the form so when you post back to the page the data is still there.

Comment: there should be a database involved somewhere

Comment: @deluxes How would I go about doing this? I've tried creating <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $reset_from_url; ?>"> but the variable still isn't available in the main section of code to process?

Comment: @user4612360 What are you considering the "main section" of the code.

Comment: @deluxes The very top section of the code opens the connection. The next checks if the values are set when the page loads, and then the third section runs when the submit button is clicked. So I'd say the third section is the main section as this will run over and over everytime the form is submitted if that makes sense? I guess what I need to do is get the values from the original url and then store them in the hidden fields, and then get them again when the form is submitted but how would I do this considering the attempt above did not work?

Answer (score 0):

As you already have tried, you have to store the token from the url in a hidden field.

```
$tokenFromUrl = $_GET['reset'];
$escapedTokenFromUrl = htmlspecialchars($tokenFromUrl);
...
<form action="reset.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $escapedTokenFromUrl; ?>" />
...
</form>
```

You used the wrong escaping function, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is meant to escape for database queries, and can only be used if you have an open database connection. Instead use `htmlspecialchars()` which escapes for HTML output.

Then your hidden tag needs a name attribute, otherways you cannot access it in the post request.

Last but not least, you should store only a hash of the token in the database, otherwise an attacker with read access to the db (SQL-injection) can request a token and use the token himself to get the account. In this small [article](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#passwordreset) i tried to show how this can be done.